# Superset - There was an error fetching the favorite status: Failed to fetch

Tags: apache-superset

when i run superset and after dashboard is open it shows
**"There was an error fetching the favorite status: Failed to fetch"**

please help me to solve this.

Comment: i also try **superset  init** but issue is not solve if i used public ip and login then it will not show this error but for security i used load balancer and add url as https so it again getting this issue
please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Set `ENABLE_PROXY_FIX=True` in `docker/pythonpath_dev/superset_config.py` (or superset/config.py) bring down docker compose and up again (or reload your app). Refernece: https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/13746